# Find the natural distinct numbers $a$ and $b$ such that $[(a+b)(x+y)]\leqslant[x+a]+[y+b]$ is true

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find the natural distinct numbers $a$ and $b$ such that $[(a+b)(x+y)]\leqslant[x+a]+[y+b]$ holds for every real numbers x and y. I used $[a]$ to denote the integer part of a.

My idea is to try to give values to x and y. For $x=1, y=2$ $a+b <= 1$. Then $a=0,b=1$ or $a=1,b=0$. I am not sure it is enough.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I gather by your example that you are including $0$ as a natural number. [that is OK but would be good to mention since for some the naturals start at $1.$]

Answer (score 2):

There is a solution $a=0$ and $b=1$ (or vice versa). If we put these numbers into the inequality it turns into: $$[x+y] \leq [x]+[y]+1,$$ which is true for any $x, y$ since $$[x+y] = [[x]+\{x\}+[y]+\{y\}] = $$ $$=[x]+[y]+[\{x\}+\{y\}] \leq [x]+[y]+1.$$

Here $\{x\}$ denotes the non-integer part of $x$. So $\{x\}=x-[x].$

Now let $a+b$ be greater than $1$, so at least $2$. Let us put $x=y=10$. The LHS then can be estimated as follows: $$[(a+b)(x+y)]= [20(a+b)] = 20(a+b) =$$ $$=a+b+ 19(a+b) \geq a+b+19 \cdot 2 =$$ $$=a+b+38 > a+b+20 = 10+a + 10+b =$$ $$=[x+a]+[y+b].$$

We got a contradiction with $[(a+b)(x+y)] \leq [x+a]+[y+b].$ So $0$ and $1$ are the only answers.